# Huge deletion error using C++ classes

Tags: c++, memory, heap-memory, delete-operator

I'm building an image analysing program in c++. It takes in a text file which holds the values to build a grey scale image. I am using the sum of squared differences to find a specific block in this image.. This is built using a matrix class in a header file so I have two overloaded constructors and a destructor which deletes the pointer to the double which allocates memory on the heap for this huge array of values (768 x 1024). This however throws out a memory error; Debug assertion failed, expression: block type is valid. I can't fathom why this is happening.. To do the SSD calculation I use two for loops; two matrix objects are manipulated one of these amendments calls one of the constructors to create a new matrix object from the getting a block from a larger matrix object. I understand that the destructor is called twice through every loop as the objects go out of scope? Is this double deletion and why the error occurs? Below are my constructors and the loops. If anyone can see why I'm getting this error I'd be very happy.

Constructors:

```
// Matrix constructor creating a new matrix object where all elements are the same number
Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double val)
{
    //cout << "Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double val) is invoked.." << endl;

    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;

    data = new double[M * N];// Initialise space for class array 'data'

    for (int i = 0; i < M* N; i++)
    {
        data[i] = val;// Set each element of the array to the same value passed to the constructor from main
    }
}

// Matrix constructor taking pointer to array as input; creates a new matrix object
Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data)
{
    //cout << "Matrix::Matrix(int sizeR, int sizeC, double* input_data) is invoked...." << endl;
    M = sizeR;
    N = sizeC;

    data = new double[M * N];// Initialise space for class array 'data'

    for (int i = 0; i < M * N; i++)
    {
        data[i] = input_data[i];// Set elements in data as elements from input_data passed to the constructor from main
    }
}
```

Destructor:

```
// Matrix destructor
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    //cout << "Matrix::~Matrix() is invoked..." << endl;
    delete data;
}
```

Code in main:

```
for (int i = 0; i < (768 - 21); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < (1024 - 21); j++)
        {
            counter++;
            clutteredBlock = cluttered.getBlock(i, (i + 21), j, (j + 21));
            diff = clutteredBlock - wallyBlock;
            diff = diff * diff;
            tempVal = diff.Sum();
            if (i == 0 && j == 0)
            {
                ssd = tempVal;
            }

            if (tempVal <= ssd)
            {
                ssd = tempVal;
                co1 = i;
                co2 = j;
            }
        }
    }
```

So M, N and data are all private class members; M and N are `int` and data is a `double*`; data being the pointer I'm trying to delete and getting nowhere with.

UPDATE: If I ignore the error I am then given a HEAP CORRUPTION error saying that I am trying to write to the heap after the buffer?

UPDATE: Assignment Operator;

```
Matrix& Matrix::operator=(const Matrix& input)
{
    //cout << "Matrix::operator= is invoked..." << endl;

    if (this == &input)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    else
    {
        delete data;
        M = input.getR();
        N = input.getC();
        data = new double[M * N];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            {
                Set(i, j, input.Get(i, j));
            }
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Any input is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: should most likely be `delete[] data;` also consider using std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr(if you dont have C++11, use std::auto_ptr), they will clear dynamic memory managed by them automatically

Comment: You need an assignment operator too. Look up *the rule of three*.

Comment: @TheOne a plain vector could be a better option. It is copyable, assignable, and not shared.

Comment: @juanchopanza true, didnt think of that, too late for my brain :/

Comment: I have an operator= among other operators.. there is too much code to post.. I have also tried `delete[]data` and it doesn't like that either I have another program that uses a derived class to do basically the same thing which worked at first and then suddenly stopped so I'm hoping if this one can be solved I can solve the other too

Comment: Do you have a copy constructor?

Comment: I was under the impression that my assignment operator replaces this.. I did have a copy constructor but deleted it when I thought it was causing problems.. I will put it back in and see how it goes

Comment: Thank you!! It was that I needed a copy constructor.. Alas my program doesn't find Wally but I'm sure with a bit of tweaking I can figure it out.. Now it actually runs :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `std::vector` for your storage. It handles allocation and deallocation automatically. Problem solved.

Comment: I appreciate the tip but the purpose of this task was to demonstrate I understand the class structure and pointers etc.. I have demonstrated my work already I would just like to solve the problem for my own piece of mind

Comment: @HollyMarieBatchelor: you should state all relevant information in the question. as it is, you have asked about something that is not your problem. whatever the constraints on the solution are, you'd better state them (e.g., that it's an assignment where you have to use raw `new`, or whatever -- the best is probably to just quote the assignment verbatim).